# Is there a word for a horizontal 1D profile for depths below ground? [geology]

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am seeking a word to describe horizontal lines (1D) cut parallel to the (mean) ground surface. The context I need it for is a plot of some variable along a horizontal line at a specific depth below the ground.

In geology, vertical sections (2D) are called cross-sections, but there is no other word for horizontal sections (happy to be proved wrong!). Vertical profiles (1D) are also called sections as well in some cases, but there is no word I can think of for a horizontal profile.

Isoline, cut line, horizontal profile, something else?

Comment: In sedimentary rock they are called layers or strata.  So perhaps a *layer* or *layer slice* or *layer cut*, or *stratum cut,* *stratum slice* or just *stratum*?

Comment: 1. Cross section can refer to a section along any of the axes, not necessarily the vertical. 2. Line, as correctly noted, is one dimensional, and does not correspond to section, which as correctly noted again, is two dimensional.

Comment: The closest that comes to mind at first thought is a *trace,* and perhaps, *profile,* both of which we do use for this. However, specifically in geology, *profile* can refer to a vertical section, similar to its use in a person's picture.

Comment: I think I need a drawing or something. :/

Comment: @Marthaª - imagine you're looking at a vertical cross-section, with ground surface at the top. Draw a horizontal line underneath it (i.e., it'll be parallel to the ground surface if the ground is flat). All depths (below mean sea level) are the same along that line. That's the line I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The word *transect* is probably close to what you need.

It is used in fields such as archaeology and biology to describe a line through an area of interest along which measurements or counts are taken.

In archaology, if there isn't enough time to conduct a full dig of an area, then a transect is taken.  The information gained along the line gives significant information about the site.

In biology, for estimating the size of a herd or flock, a transect is defined and a count made along it.  This can be extrapolated to estimate the full size.  It also gives a view of the density of the herd or flock.

This would fit with your geological requirement.  A line along which you profile your variable.

Comment: Excellent find. It does not necessarily mean "below ground," but still, it seems to work pretty well. "A straight line or narrow section through an object or natural feature or across the earth’s surface, along which observations are made or measurements taken." (ODO: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transect )

Answer (score -1):

horizon？not necessary 1D though.

horizon is widely used in Geology, Petroleum Geology, petroleum earth modeling. It basically refers to a marker based on depositional environment, and seismic interpretation. People normally pick up a horizon for a certain formation top, bottom, or interested target zone or certain depth.  A horizon is not flat in almost all the cases, which I am not sure is the word wanted here.